# Java class not visible to spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to spring-boot and attempting to populate a property in a spring-boot XML with a function return value from a Java class but the class doesn't seem to be visible to the spring-boot loader.
I'm probably just missing an annotation or something but any input would be great.

Here is my Java class and method:

```
public class AppMqttConfig {

    @Bean
    public SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory()
            throws Exception {
        
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

        String caCrtFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/non-prod/AmazonRootCA1.pem").getFile().getAbsolutePath();

        String crtFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/non-prod/certificate.pem.crt").getFile().getAbsolutePath();

        String keyFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/non-prod/private.pem.key").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
        
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

And here is where I'm referencing the return value of getSocketFactory:

```
`<bean id="pahoMqttClientFactory"
      class="org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory">
    <property name="connectionOptions">
        <bean class="org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions">
            <property name="serverURIs">
                <list>
                    <value>${mqtt.broker.url}</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="connectionTimeout" value="${mqtt.client.connectionTimeout}" />
            <property name="keepAliveInterval" value="${mqtt.client.keepAliveInterval}" />
            <property name="cleanSession" value="${mqtt.session.clean}" />
            <property name="socketFactory" value="#{AppMqttConfig.getSocketFactory()}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>`
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

EL1008E: Property or field AppMqttConfig cannot be found on object of type org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: @Service annotation for public class AppMqttConfig or create bean in xml for this class